# How to add a play icon to Image on CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm looking for how to add a play icon to Image on CSS.

I tried this code, but it doesn't appear right I want it to appear on the center :

```
    .video { position: relative; }

.video a {
   position: absolute;
   display: block;
   background: url(http://www.slatecube.com/images/play-btn.png);
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   top: 20px;
   left: 20px;
}
```

html :

```
<div class="video" >  
<img  style="height:200px"src="http://san.capitalafrique.com/imatin.net/articles/images/lionel-messi.jpg"  />
    <a href="#"></a>
</div>
```

here is the jsFiddle :

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/z5y8ht4y/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/z5y8ht4y/1/)

you should set background-size

```
.video a {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  background: url(http://www.slatecube.com/images/play-btn.png);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 75px;
  left: 150px;
  background-size: 50px 50px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! How to make the whole image clickble ?

Comment: The anchor element in your example doesn't sit over the image, and actually flows all the way to the end of the page.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this without your image, which should reduce load times: http://jsfiddle.net/t8skLwcb/

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.video {
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  height: 200px;
  width: 357px;
  background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b8/Messi_vs_Nigeria_2018.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
}
.video a {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.video a .circle {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 3px solid white;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
}
.video a .circle .triangle {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10px solid white;
  transform: translate(-25%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="video">
  <a href="#">
    <span class="circle">
      <span class="triangle"></span>
    </span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use background-size:contain; and center the background:

```
background: url(http://www.slatecube.com/images/play-btn.png) no-repeat center;
background-size:contain;
```

JsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/z5y8ht4y/2/

Answer (score 0):

> For click even use jquery or javascript

**Jquery**

---

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/z5y8ht4y/4/

And reduce width of play button to **11%** if you not reduce width  then in left region you want be click

see this example with 100% width of play http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/z5y8ht4y/3

```
$('img').click(function(){
alert('clicked')

})
```

Or use z-index if you want 100% width but it may be break your layout because play has position : absolute

---

**Javascript**:

---

**HTML**

```
<img onclick="clickfunction()" style="height:200px" src="http://san.capitalafrique.com/imatin.net/articles/images/lionel-messi.jpg" /> <a href="#"></a>
```

**Script**

```
clickfunction = function () {
   alert()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS only

```
.video a {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    background: url(http: //www.slatecube.com/images/play-btn.png);
    height: 50 px;
    width: 100 %;
    top: 92 px;
    background - size: 50 px 50 px;
    background - repeat: no - repeat;
    background - position: center;
}

.video {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to add a new question. You can simply edit your previous one.

Answer (score 0):

may be this ? (if you know the size of the image/s)

```css
.video { 
    position: relative; 
    background-image: url('http://san.capitalafrique.com/imatin.net/articles/images/lionel-messi.jpg');
    width:400px;
    height:200px;
}
.link{
    width:100%; 
    height:100%; 
    position:absolute; 
    left:0px; 
    top:0px; 
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
.link:hover{
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
}
.playBtn {
   position: absolute;
   background-image:url("http://www.slatecube.com/images/play-btn.png");
   background-size: 150px 150px;
   height: 150px;
   width: 150px;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index:999;
}
```

```html
<div class="video" >  
    <a href="#" class="link">
        <div class="playBtn"></div>
    </a>
</div>
```