# Vertically center a glyphicon over an img in a div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I have a `div` that houses a `glyphicon` and an `img`. The image is a thumbnail for a video and I'd like to put the play icon centered vertically and horizontally on top of that thumbnail. The markup looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <h2>{{video.title}}</h2>
        <p>{{video.description}}</p>
        <div class="video-thumbnail">  <--- ITEM OF INTEREST
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle"></i>
            <img ng-src="{{video.thumbnail}}" alt="{{video.title}}" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive center-block"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `less` that I've applied, past Bootstrap, looks like this:

```
featured-video {
  .video-thumbnail {
    text-align: center;

    &>.glyphicon-play-circle {
      font-size: 500%;
    }
  }
}
```

The computed `css` for the `video-thumbnail` looks like this:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
display: block;
font-family: source-sans-pro, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
height: 818.328125px;
line-height: 20px;
text-align: center;
width: 1110px;
```

The computed `css` for the `glyphicon` looks like this:

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
box-sizing: border-box;
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
display: inline-block;
font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
font-size: 70px;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
height: 70px;
line-height: 70px;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
top: 1px;
width: 70px;
```

The computed `css` for the `img` looks like this:

```
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
border-bottom-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-bottom-width: 1px;
border-image-outset: 0px;
border-image-repeat: stretch;
border-image-slice: 100%;
border-image-source: none;
border-image-width: 1;
border-left-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
border-left-style: solid;
border-left-width: 1px;
border-right-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
border-right-style: solid;
border-right-width: 1px;
border-top-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
border-top-left-radius: 4px;
border-top-right-radius: 4px;
border-top-style: solid;
border-top-width: 1px;
box-sizing: border-box;
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
display: block;
font-family: source-sans-pro, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
height: 743.328125px;
line-height: 20px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
max-width: 100%;
padding-bottom: 4px;
padding-left: 4px;
padding-right: 4px;
padding-top: 4px;
text-align: center;
transition-delay: 0s;
transition-duration: 0.2s;
transition-property: all;
transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
vertical-align: middle;
width: 1110px;
```

### NOTE

I do need this to work on mobile devices so I'm leery about applying an actual size to the thumbnail. The videos will be recorded in 720p but that really shouldn't matter because this is just a thumbnail.

### What I've Tried

I have tried setting the `vertical-align: middle` on the `video-thumbnail` and `glyphicon`; together and exclusively.

I've tried setting the `line-height: 100%` on the `video-thumbnail` along with the `vertical-align: middle` and that didn't have any effect.

I've tried another number of random modifications that didn't have any effect but also weren't really as methodical as the aforementioned.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You said icon over image, but I don't see any position absolute set.

Comment: I've given an answer to a similar question that may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/a/31048277/2117156

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Absolute positioning might be the ticket.

```
.video-thumbnail {
    position: relative;
}
.video-thumbnail .glyphicon {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -10px; /* half icon's height */
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -10px; /* half icon's width */
    z-index: 999;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/0j76700t/)**

Comment: Fiddle updated with embiggened icon and hover effect.

Comment: *Embiggened*: "To enlarge or grow; to make or become bigger." <-- don't worry, I had to Google it

Answer (score 2):

Take a look of CSS [`transform`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d), it works well for centering an unknown size element.

Browser support IE9+

<kbd>**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/v2m2a3ec/)**</kbd>

```
.video-thumbnail {
    position: relative;
}
.glyphicon-play-circle {
    font-size: 500%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%; top: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: Nice. No need to deal with margins if IE8 is out of the picture.

Comment: Thanks @isherwood that trick is often used to solve complex cases.

Answer (score 0):

Use vertical-align for inner html of video-thumbnail:

```
.video-thumbnail i, .video-thumbnail img{
   display: inline-block !important;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```