# how can I add icon at the center of bootstrap5 card image

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

Is there anyway I can display an icon at the center of the `bootstrap-5` card image? I have an icon that I want to display at the center of my card image, but I don't know how to do that using either `CSS` or `Bootstrap-5`, how can I do that please? I have try using [This method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31046949/how-to-add-a-play-icon-to-image-on-css) but the image is not inside a card, I also try to use [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31046949/how-to-add-a-play-icon-to-image-on-css) but it will not work because the image is not at the card.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Videos</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
    href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.4/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
</head>
<style>
    .image-thumbnail{
        object-fit: cover;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .my_card{
        height: 100%;
    }
</style>
<body class="m-5">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <a href="">All</a>
                        <a href="">All</a>
                        <a href="">All</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-md-9">

               <div class="row">

                {% for video in my_videos %}
                <div class="col-md-4 my-2">
                    <a href="{% url 'Play-Video' video.slug %}">
                        <div class="card my_card">
                            <img class="image-thumbnail" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSnkEY_ZgFq4R5FRz-4d9iamx8OKOhneZTm5vKRkwizmnycE-9uI6Tea6AHLQmm5qPq_xg&usqp=CAU" alt="">
                            <i style="font-size: 60px;" class="bi bi-play"></i>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <img src="" alt="">
                                <p class="card-title">
                                    {{ video.title }}
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                {% endfor %}

               </div>

            </div>
            

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <nav aria-label="...">
                <ul class="pagination">
                    <a class="page-link" href="">1</a>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it differently. Using absolute units (i.e., `px`) is not the best option. Why? Because it might look good on the screen you're working on, but it will certainly look different (i.e., won't be centered) on a smaller or bigger screen. Instead, use the relative units (i.e., `%`). Also, I added `.img_wrapper` container.

*Note: The CSS I added could also be applied via Bootstrap classes, but I didn't do it on purpose, so you can better see what CSS I've added.*

See the snippet below.

```css
.image-thumbnail {
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 100%;
}

.my_card {
  height: 100%;
}

.img_wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

img.image-thumbnail {
  width: 100%;
}

.bi {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Videos</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.4/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
</head>

<body class="m-5">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <a href="">All</a>
            <a href="">All</a>
            <a href="">All</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="row">
          {% for video in my_videos %}
          <div class="col-md-4 my-2">
            <a href="{% url 'Play-Video' video.slug %}">
              <div class="card my_card">
                <div class="img_wrapper">
                  <img class="image-thumbnail" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSnkEY_ZgFq4R5FRz-4d9iamx8OKOhneZTm5vKRkwizmnycE-9uI6Tea6AHLQmm5qPq_xg&usqp=CAU" alt="">
                  <i style="font-size: 60px;" class="bi bi-play"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                  <img src="" alt="">
                  <p class="card-title">
                    {{ video.title }}
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
          {% endfor %}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <nav aria-label="...">
        <ul class="pagination">
          <a class="page-link" href="">1</a>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem by adding these `css` code:

```
.bi {
        position: absolute;
        font-size: 60px;
        margin-left: 100px;
        margin-top: 50px;
        background-color: white;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Videos</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
    href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.4/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
</head>
<style>
    .image-thumbnail{
        object-fit: cover;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .my_card{
        height: 100%;
    }
    .bi {
        position: absolute;
        font-size: 60px;
        margin-left: 100px;
        margin-top: 50px;
        background-color: white;
    }
</style>
<body class="m-5">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <a href="">All</a>
                        <a href="">All</a>
                        <a href="">All</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-md-9">

               <div class="row">

                {% for video in my_videos %}
                <div class="col-md-4 my-2">
                    <a href="{% url 'Play-Video' video.slug %}">
                        <div class="card my_card">
                            <img class="image-thumbnail" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSnkEY_ZgFq4R5FRz-4d9iamx8OKOhneZTm5vKRkwizmnycE-9uI6Tea6AHLQmm5qPq_xg&usqp=CAU" alt="">
                            <i class="bi bi-play"></i>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <img src="" alt="">
                                <p class="card-title">
                                    {{ video.title }}
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                {% endfor %}

               </div>

            </div>
            

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <nav aria-label="...">
                <ul class="pagination">
                    <a class="page-link" href="">1</a>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```